# XQuery - pass HTML in a parameter to XSLT

Tags: xslt, xquery

In XQuery 3.1 I have a function which outputs a snippet of HTML. This function:

```
declare function document:doc-citation($currentdoc as xs:string)
{
  let $citation :=
        (<div>
                <p  class="cite-document">To cite this document: </span>
                <p>{common:cite-doc($currentdoc,"html")}</p>
        </div>)

 return $citation               
 };
```

Outputs this:

```
<div>
  <p class="cite-document"><span>To cite this document: </span></p>
  <p><span>Fooname. <i>Foo title</i>. Foopublisher. 2018.</span></p>
</div>
```

Now I want to pass this complete HTML into a parameter for XSLT. So in an XQuery function `transform:transform()` that otherwise works fine for the other (string) parameters, I attempt to pass the HTML like so:

```
<param name="paramCitation" value="{document:doc-citation($mydoc)}"/>
```

Which XSLT 2.0 should pickup through:

```
<xsl:param name="paramCitation"/>
```

And output the HTML through this XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="paramCitation"/>
```

I've never tried to pass HTML through an XQuery/XSLT parameter before.

I think somewhere I'm not handling the HTML correctly in the XQuery parameter, or not handling the parameter output correctly in XSLT (HTML/string conversion problems)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we had that problem in some of your earlier attempts, at least with the eXist `transform:transform` function you can only pass in strings; on the other hand I showed how to construct the XSLT on the fly in XQuery where you would put your node value from XQuery directly into the `xsl:param` element with e.g. `<xsl:param name="paramCitation">{document:doc-citation($mydoc)}</xsl:param>`, you can then use that dynamically constructed XSLT as the code for the `transform:transform` function.

Comment: If you want to use the normal parameter approach of the `transform:transform` function with string values then you would need to serialize the nodes first on the XQuery side e.g. `serialize(document:doc-citation($mydoc))`, but I am not sure you really want to pass around strings and then in XSLT would want to output the HTML as a string.

Comment: On your first point - I really didn't want to dynamically construct this entire XSLT document in this specific instance - it's a fairly massive, complicated transformation that would be, for me, quite difficult to maintain (it's challenging as it is, as you've seen). In this case I could take the HTML and build it in the XSLT file itself, but there's certain logic that I wanted to maintain solely in one place : XQuery. But if serializing isn't good practice, then I may have to maintain logic in two places.

Comment: For your approach as shown, what kind of XPath type do you expect to have for the `xsl:param name="paramCitation"` on the XSLT side? What kind of value, a string with the serialization of that (X)HTML node you constructed in XQuery? If you use `<xsl:value-of select="paramCitation"/>` on the XSLT side, which output method do you have, what kind of result do you construct? If that is HTML then any string with markup would be outputted escaped so the result document would not contain a `div` element node but rather a text node with the HTML markup.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just realising this problem of types. I think you are right that passing the HTML through a parameter is just a hack. I'll build this out in XSL and live with logic in two places....